# Using FQL to query insights and likes for Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, authentication, access-token, facebook-insights

We run some facebook pages for our clients and we'd like to run off some reports, like many people LIKED those pages yesterday, for example.

I can see that this can be done by FQL, but you need an access_token to run the queries using Facebook Graph API in (C#).

For these Facebook pages there isn't an app associated with them, so without app_id how can I get authenticated to be able to run those queries ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an app that you then use to retrieve the stats.

If you then get an access token for a user that is an admin of the pages and request the read_insight extended permission you can get the insights data for each page, which will give you plenty of stats to report in a handy JSON format.

See here for more details on the insights in the graph API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

Comment: Thanks for that. I tested it out use the Graph API explorer. Since I was admin of the pages, I was able to query the stats for those pages.

Comment: In Addition, for getting page_likes/page_fans for a specific, it looks like its not possible - this has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085412/how-can-i-retrieve-the-number-of-fans-my-facebook-page-had-on-a-given-day